# Print the full name of user in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I need to print the full name of the current user in the console, I have this code that does what I need but only partially

```
NET USER %username% /DOMAIN | FIND /I "Full name" >tmp.txt
set /p VAR=<tmp.txt
echo %VAR%
del tmp.txt
```

Because the result of the print is for example "Full Name                            Juan Perez"
And the only thing I need is "Juan Perez"

Is there a way to do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically,

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=2*delims= " %%b IN ('NET USER %username% /DOMAIN 2^>nul ^|find /I "Full name"') DO SET "var=%%c"
ECHO Full name : "%var%"
GOTO :EOF
```

but `NET USER %username% /DOMAIN` returns an error for me.

The `2^>nul` redirects errors. the `^` before `>` and `|` tells `cmd` the character is part of the `'`-enclosed command to be executed, not of the `for` itself.

Documentation for `for` can be found by executing `for /?` from the prompt, or reading thousands of examples on SO

Comment: surely it doesn't work for you `NET USER %username% /DOMAIN` because your pc is not within a domain

I tried what you told me but it does not return the result, it simply returns the empty field `Full name : ""`

I guess this happens because you can't load the full name data inside the variable maybe?

Comment: Very well could be, Since I'm unaware of the precise response you are getting from `NET USER %username% /DOMAIN`, I can only guess that `tmp.txt` contains `Full Name Juan Perez` but it would appear that this may be followed by some empty lines. Try ...`DO if not defined var SET...` and for safety's sake, a `set "var="` in a new line before the `for`.

Comment: Excuse me, it is already solved with the code that you told me in the first comment, the "Full name" variable does not work for me because my system is in Spanish, so I have to change it to "Nombre Completo"