# Is there how to get a Windows user's full name on a Bash/Shell script file on Git Bash?

Tags: bash, cmd, git-bash

I attempted several tests, running a Perl command and a Command Prompt command on Git Bash, but they were not successful due to the errors.

Remember that I can not use PowerShell on my company's computer because it is blocked. I can use only Command Prompt and Git Bash, but I need only Git Bash and a Bash script. I do not want a Batch file.

I referred to:

- [How to get system user full name on Windows in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081246/how-to-get-system-user-full-name-on-windows-in-perl)
- [Print the full name of user in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72640132/print-the-full-name-of-user-in-batch)

I tested on a Shell Script file on Git Bash:

```bash
MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 net user %USERNAME% /domain |find /I "Nome completo"
```

I received the error:

```
find: ‘/I’: No such file or directory
find: ‘Nome completo’: No such file or directory
Could not find username.

For more info, type NET HELPMSG 2221.
```

Also:

```bash
perl -MWin32API::Net -E "Win32API::Net::UserGetInfo('',Win32::LoginName(), 10, my $info = {} ); say $info->{fullName}"
```

But I received the error:

```
Can't locate Win32API/Net.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Win32API::Net module) (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

Is there how to get a full name of a current Windows user on a Bash/Shell script on Git Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a bash shell, `find` would be `/usr/bin/find`, that is `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\find.exe`, not `C:\Windows\System32\find.exe`.

In that context (Git bash), you can use `grep` instead:

```
MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 net user ${USERNAME} /domain | grep -i "Nome completo"
```

I followed "[How do I get the current user's username in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19306837/6309)", but the environment variable `USERNAME` should still be visible in Git bash.
The syntax is just different.

Comment: Because of `%USERNAME%`, I received the error `Could not find username`.

Comment: @Oo'- True, I suspect `${USERNAME}` would work better?

Comment: It crashed, but I checked `echo user` to see if it exists. It does not exist. I tried `whoami`, but `net` took a lot of time to output. Then I found another solution: `export WINDOWS_USER_PATH=$(MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 cmd /c echo '%USERNAME%'); MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 net user ${WINDOWS_USER_PATH} /domain | grep -i "Nome completo"` and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Oo'- I meant `${USERNAME}` not `${USER}`. I just tested it: it does work.

Comment: With `${USERNAME}`, it worked. An elegant and short solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Oo'- Great, well done!